# Stripe - Creating Charge

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment

Working on integrating stipe. Everything seems to work on the front end but on the server side code the token is empty and it is not successfully charging to Stripe. Can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
   app.post('/apple-pay', function(req, res, next) {

    // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
    // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
    var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_XXX");

    // Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
    // Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
    const token = req.body.stripeToken;
    console.log(token)
     const charge = stripe.charges.create({
      amount: 999,
      currency: 'usd',
      description: 'Example charge',
       source: token,

    }, function(err, charge) {
         if(err){
                req.flash("error", err.message);
                res.redirect("back");
            } else {

            }
    });
    });
```

Comment: How do you mean empty? empty string?

Comment: token is undefined

Comment: Could you also show us your client code posting to the server please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044909/stripe-node-js-payment-request-button

Answer (score 0):

Before **Creating charge**, You should **create Customer**. After Charge Works.

Sample Code. (ES6)

```
let customer = await payStripe.customers.create({
            email: req.body.stripeEmail,
            source: req.body.stripeToken
});

//After Created Customer...

if(customer){

 let charge = await payStripe.charges.create({

            amount: req.body.amount,

            description: req.body.description,

            currency: 'usd',

            customer: customer.id
        });


}
```

I hope it's work fine.

Comment: I think its also possible to charge without creating a customer

Answer (score 0):

In your frontend code from the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044909/stripe-node-js-payment-request-button) you passed the POST body as

`JSON.stringify({token: ev.token.id})`

which means that the Stripe token is actually in the `token` POST parameter, not `stripeToken`. So you need to do

`const token = req.body.token;`

instead.